# Vue.js - How to add html tag in the starting of string when match found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Suppose I have a string like this `"hey this is StackOverflow"` and my `substring` is `"flow"`.
While searching `substring` in the string it returns true using `*indexOf*`

What I want in this like when it matches the `substring` which is *flow* it appends the Html tag in between this:

Example:

Input: `"hey this is StackOverflow"`

Output: `"hey this is StackOver <'sometag'> flow <'/sometag'> "`

The below code returns the true but didn't get any idea how to append the Html Tag in this.

```
substring.indexOf(string)
```

Please help me out from this it is very helpful because I'm not much more aware with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try string replace method :

```js
let str= "hey this is StackOverflow, flow"


let newStr=str.replace(/flow/g,' <h1>flow</h1>')

console.log(newStr)
```

Then you could render it in the template using `v-html` directive like :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
      el: '#app',

      data() {
        return {
          str: "hey this is StackOverflow"
        }
      },

      computed: {
        newStr() {
        return  this.str.replace(/flow/g, '<b>flow</b>')
        }
      }})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">

  <div v-html="str"></div>
  <div v-html="newStr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest to change it to `replaceAll` so it will work for subsequent occurences as well. Besides that, great answer.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that you were using a regex, my bad. :) (even though I still think `replaceAll` is abit cleaerer in this case, but it both works)

Comment: the replaceAll method is used when you want to replace the exact matching string but `//g` replaces any regex pattern, the two solutions are useful and they depend on the use case

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim - I have a string in which firstly I'm checking substring exists or not it exists then I'm replacing the string with substring with HTML tag and return the final string

Comment: please provide all these details in your question and i will reformulate my answer based on that

Answer (score 1):

what you need is `string.replace("sometag","<sometag>")` instead of `substring.indexOf(string)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let given_string = "hey this is StackOverflow" , search = "flow", my_tag = "Tag" , tagged = "";

if(given_string.indexOf(search) !== -1)
  {
    let splited = given_string.split(search);
    splited.forEach(item => {
      if(item !== "")
        {
          tagged += item + " " + "<"+ my_tag +">" + search + "</"+ my_tag +">";
        }
    })
    
    
    
  }

console.log(tagged);
```